# Module versions in a crash dump

Tags: winapi, crash-dumps, module-versions

Is there a way to figure out versions of modules that were loaded into the process' address space when the process crashed from a crash dump that was generated by the process calling the MiniDumpWriteDump function? In other words, is any version information stored inside a dmp file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

load your minidump into WinDbg, then there's a Modules item off the Debug menu that shows checksum and timestamp information. That may be enough info for your purposes.

You can get the version from all loaded modules by typing "LM v" in the command window, in WinDBG. The list is long and you get lots, including the Product and File version strings. However, I think it fetches this information from locally-stored modules that it loads, making sure its got the right ones from checksum information it uses to match them to the symbol files.

Comment: Man, you're awesome! Having timestamps is totally better than not having anything.

PS. I'm wondering why didn't they add the version data to PDBs though - that would make life so much easier...

Comment: Because version info is an added resource, not necessarily part of the compiled binary that's needed to make it work. I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Load your dump file to WinDbg and type this command:

```
lm v <name_of_module> // shows information about specified module
```

`lm v` will show you information about all modules.